# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString *' error

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

/Users/..../Desktop/apps/..../..../TableViewController.m:147:69: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

this is the code

```
    NSString * vak = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lesson"];
    NSString * Lraar = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"teacher"];
    NSString * begin = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"start"];
    NSString * lok = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"room"];
    NSString * end = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:@"end"];
```

Comment: -1 for not identifying the failing line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line you typed `objectAtIndex:@"end"` instead of `objectForKey:@"end"`.